# Auto updating similar formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, spreadsheet, worksheet-function

I'm trying to see if there's a way to get my Excel sheet to auto update with new formulas as I enter it.

For example if D4 down to D27 was the same formula(=SUM(B4/25)) and I wanted to change it too =SUM(B4/25)*0.75, would I be able to just change one of them and have the rest follow suit or would I have to put them in manually?

Comment: does CTRL+D fill down do the trick?

Comment: CTRL+D fills only one cell, unless I'm missing something in the settings. But it is a step in the right direction! Thanks for the response! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **semi-automatically update** a column of formulas with the following procedure.

1. Change the formula in the top most cell of your range
2. Select the complete range
3. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to `fill down` the formula from the top cell into each remaining cell in the range.

#### Given your example:

- Enter the new formula in cell D4
- Select D4 through D27
- Press the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> combination to fill the new formula into all the cells.